# Fixed-point functions in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Suppose we have a function `y=f(x)`, we can represent it is a relation `f(X,Y)`.

For example, we can represent the function, f(x):x/2`, as relation in Prolog:

```
f(X, Y):-
    Y is div(X, 2).
```

We might want to ask about `f^2`, `f^3` --- what is the output of f applied to itself, once, twice, or more times:

```
% Apply X_ to f(X,X_) N times.
applyn(P, X, 1, Y) :-
   call(P, X, Y).

applyn(P, X, N, Y) :-
   N_ is N-1,
   call(P, X, X_),
   applyn(P, X_, N_, Y).

?- applyn(f, 512, 2, Y)
128
```

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/fixedpoint.swinb

As a function, we might be interested in it’s fixed point `X=f(X)`.
In the above example, `0=f(0)` is a fixed point because `0=0/2`.

Converting a function `y=f(x)` to a prolog relationship `f(X,Y)` we might want to ask:

- for some initial input `X0`, what is the terminal value `Xt`, that finds `f(Xt,Xt)` as the final position of the sequence:

```
f(X0, X1)
f(X1, X2)
f(X2, X3)
...
f(Xt, Xt)   % X=Y, so terminate. Equivalent to `x = f(x)` in function-land.
```

- how many steps does it taking for the sequence to converge on a fixed point: (f(Xt,Xt)).

Generally, we should also be able to do this for symbolic functions:

```
g(a,b).
g(b,c).
g(c,c).
?- applyn(g, a, 1000, Y).
c
```

... and so we should be able to ask:

```
?- fixed_point2(f, 4, T, N).  % f:x/2
T=0, N=4
% f(4,2)
% f(2,1)
% f(1,0)
% f(0,0)
```

```
?- fixed_point2(g, a, T, N)   % g is a finite set of grounded facts.
T=c, N=3 
% f(a,b)
% f(b,c)
% f(c,c)
```

Comment: When you say *what is the value of `Y` for `f(Y,Y)` for a starting `X`?* I assume you mean, *given `X`, for what values of `N`, if any, does `applyn(f, X, N, X)` hold true? I'm not sure how to distinguish your first and second questions.

Comment: One is asking, what the fixes point value. The other is asking, how many steps to the fixed point.

Comment: I’ll update the question

Comment: I see. I'm not in a position at the moment to formulate a detailed answer, but I have the following comments about what an answer looks like: (1) you would need to use CLP(FD) library and avoid `is/2`, and (2) Prolog needs to know the domain of possible `X` to explore, which can also be specified with CLP(FD) (*e.g.*, `X in ...`). Once that's done, Prolog can try to find solutions to the query, `applyn(f, 1, X, X)`.

Comment: I'm not sure `is` should be particularly relevant. If use had a function: f(a)->b,  f(b)->c, ,  f(c)->c, then f has a fixed point c that is the sink for a and b. a and b need not by numbers. (Actually I'm more interested in solutions that as not related to numbers.

Comment: Well you're currently using `is/2` which only operates on numbers. Your title says "Fixed-point functions..." Prolog has predicates, not functions, except in the context of numbers and "fixed-point"  I thought was a reference to "fixed-point" arithmetic, which was my bad. For your numeric example, the avoidance of `is/2` is quite relevant. If you have a non-numeric example, perhaps you could show it. My comment about defining the domain space of solution options is relevant regardless. Prolog needs to know where it's picking candidate solutions from.

Comment: Isn't there a general relationship that any function `y=f(x)` can be expressed as a relationship between two variables `f(X,Y)` ?  In neither function-land, nor relationship-land do we need to say, x or X is a number. (You can have functions that relate  string, numbers, or our functions, in the same way that this is possible for relationship, no?).

In talking about a fixed point of f for seed X0, I don't think we need to say that X0 is number, right? Aren't fix points are an abstract algebraic relationship, not a numeric one.

Comment: If the issue is about being able to whether X=Y, this could be a parameter: `same(X,Y):-X=Y` for algebreic (symbolic) object,  `same(X,Y):- X is Y`  for numbers.
I don't think this `is` inside f should be important, right?

Comment: I've updated the question -- I'm more interested in fixed points of any `f`, not just `f(x):x/2`

Comment: *Isn't there a general relationship that any function `y=f(x)` can be expressed as a relationship between two variables `f(X,Y)`*. Sure. In Prolog, the sky's the limit on what `f(X, Y)` could mean. In the most general sense, it just defines a relationship between `X` and `Y`. Ideally, if one is specified, it can give you solutions for the other. Or even if neither is specified, it might provide a pattern that they must match in order for `f(X, Y)` to succeed. In Prolog, `f` is a *predicate*, not a *function* for that reason. Although it sounds like you're limiting it to functional behavior.

Comment: I'm still puzzling over your term *fixed point*. Do you mean for a specific binding for `X` there is at most one binding for `Y` that causes `f(X,Y)` to succeed? I'll still argue that, for numbers, `same(X,Y):- X is Y` isn't really a proper relation. But since you are treating this as a function (in your example it would necessarily mean `X` is a function of `Y`) then I suppose it can work. It's just not Prolog-y.

Comment: If, for `f(X,Y)` then `same(X,Y)` is true, then Y is a fixed point of `f` (we can defer upon the definition of `same`). A fixed point terminates a self-application series:   `f(X0, X1), f(X1, X2), f(X2, X3) ...  f(XA, XB)` where `same(XA,XB)` holds.

Comment: Ok. If you're not just dealing with numbers, then `same(X, X)` would be the implementation of `same/2`. `same(X, Y) :- X is Y.` is strictly numeric (`is/2` is a numeric operation: it evalutates one argument as a numeric expression and binds it to the other argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fixed_point(F, X0, Same, N, Xt):-
    call(F, X0, Xt),
    call(Same, X0, Xt),
    N is 0.
        
fixed_point(F, X0, Same, N, Xt):-
    call(F, X0, X1),
    \+ call(Same, X0, X1),
    fixed_point(F, X1, Same, N_, Xt),
    N is N_+1.
```

```
     same_unify(X,Y):- X=Y.
     same_is(X,Y):- X is Y.
        
     g(a,b).
     g(b,c).
     g(c,c).
        
     f(X, Y):- Y is div(X,2).
```

Gets

```
?- fixed_point(g, a, same_unify, N, Xt).
N=2, Xt=c
?- fixed_point(f, 512, same_is, N, Xt).
N= 10, Xt=0
```

For extra, points:

- can it be made tail recursive?
- avoid redundant call to `call(F, X0, Xt)` each iteration
- unify terminal condition with 0 as the parameter (does this allow indexing)
- can it the negation +, be removed?
- can it work without the Same parameter (or infer it)?
- can it work without call?